# Apache NiFi DBCPConnectionPool ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended for 'select 1 from dual;'

Tags: apache-nifi, oracle12c, ojdbc

I am running a simple query with ExecuteSQL to Oracle 12c on NiFi:

> SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
> https://pasteboard.co/JCkMVmR.png

With configuration - DBCPConnectionPool 1.11.4:
https://pasteboard.co/JCkiOnr.png

and getting following error:

https://pasteboard.co/JCjGreC.png

```
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:444)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPService.getConnection(DBCPService.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy138.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.AbstractExecuteSQL.onTrigger(AbstractExecuteSQL.java:236)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1176)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:213)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:669)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:544)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:753)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:440)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
```

NiFi nifi-1.11.4-RC1
Oracle 12.2.0.1.0
ojdbc8.jar (12.2.0.1)
DBCPConnectionPool 1.11.4

Any suggestion for this? Thanks in advance!

**edit**

As suggested in comments, tried the version **without** semicolon`;` and got different error:
`org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: org.apach e.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal initial character: 1`

Comment: remove semicolon `;` from query

Comment: Also the same error https://pasteboard.co/JCkbV0x.png

Comment: The error seems to be coming from the pool creation. not the query you are trying to execute; so how is the pool defined? Does it have a validation query, maybe one that defaults to non-Oracle syntax? From a quick search, [the NiFi docs](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-dbcp-service-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool/index.html) do refer to a validation query.

Comment: edit your question and show the parameters of connection pool. try to remove validation query - what's the result?

Comment: The validation query is in place: https://pasteboard.co/JCkiOnr.png The pool defined on screenshot is DBCPConnectionPool 1.11.4. As in my comment response to @daggett before, the erroneous query showing is the one put inside the ExecuteSQL (1.11.4). Not the validation query.

Comment: @daggett I tried removing the validation query, the same errors appear with semicolon and without..

Comment: should not be. just doublecheck that you are modifying correct connectionpool. can't create connection pool (aka can't connect) -  this is because you have `;` in validation query. so, or you have to remove `;` from it or remove whole validation query. please change the query that you are executing. btw, show the parameters of executeSQL processor. and show the error you have after you fixed validation query.

Comment: @daggett Like I wrote before, I removed validation query completely and checked the version with and without semicolon. I was using the right connection pool. Here's the parameters of ExecuteSQL: https://pasteboard.co/JCkMVmR.png

Comment: i see `;` in your query now.

Comment: Have you restarted to make sure the config change was picked up?

Comment: Have you tried `select 1 as test from dual` ?

Comment: @Sdairs This is the solution to the issue! Thanks!

Comment: @Tomasch awesome - Ill add it as an answer incase others find this question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use dual you need to set a name for the returned value so that the result can map to a valid avro schema. e.g.

```
select 1 as test from dual
```

which returns `test: 1` rather than just `1`.